# Python FOR loop character counting

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style, computer-science, charactercount

Here's my code for my class, i'm suppose to use a for loop to count the number of times a certain character is used, I was told to do each character instead of a line, what does this mean? Besides the basic string line, I have no clue most of the time, I'm currently online and can never understand what my teacher means most of the time. This is the only code creation I have had trouble with character counting.

```
   def main():

        try:

                uppercase = 0
                lowercase = 0
                digits = 0
                whitespace = 0

                string_input = open('text.txt', 'r')

                character_strings = string_input.readlines()

                for i in range(len(character_strings)):
                    character_strings[i] = character_strings[i].rstrip("\n")

                uppercase = uppercase_counter(character_strings)
                lowercase = lowercase_counter(character_strings)
                digits = digit_counter(character_strings)

                count1 = 0
                count2 = 0
                count3 = 0

                for ch in string:
                        if ch.isupper():
                                count1 = count1 + 1

                return count1
                print(count1)

                for ch in string:
                        if ch.islower():
                                count2 = count2 + 1

                return count2
                print(count2)

                for ch in string:
                        if ch.isdigit():
                                count3 = count3 + 1    

                return count3
                print(count3)

        except IOError:
                print("The file could not be found")
        except IndexError:
                print("There was an indexing error")
        except:
                print("An error occurred")

main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "count the number of times a certain character is used"? Are you give a particular character and a particular file, and you are to count how many times that character is in the file? Or are you to do that for all characters that are in the file, or for all possible characters, or something else?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
You've posted code, but you haven't described a particular problem, and I doubt that this is the minimal code to exhibit the problem.

Comment: I have to input a .txt file to be read and used, yes. I have to than use a for loop to to "count" the number of times it is used in the file, my four characters to find are, the number of uppercase letters/lowercase, digits used, and # of white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, never use tabs in Python. Always use 4-spaces indent, it's a common practice. It's convenient when everybody does such simple things the same way, helps to understand someone else's code.

What they are telling you:

```
character_strings = string_input.readlines()
```

this line reads all text from the `string_input` file, splits it by newline symbol and returns a list of lines. As I can see, there is no need to care about lines, you can read the whole text to a single long string

```
string = string_input.read()
```

So you should pass that very string to all `_counter`s you have.

```
uppercase = uppercase_counter(string)
```

And so on.

About doing the same with for loops, you need to iterate over symbols of the string

```
for symbol in string:
    if symbol.isupper():
        count1 = count1 + 1
```

Same with `islower` and `isdigit`

(Naming variables like `something1`, `something2` and `something3` is usually a bad practice. Perhaps you should think of better names.)

P. S. You forgot to close the file. Insert `string_input.close()` before first `except`. It's always recommended to close a file when done with it.

Comment: Thank you! I am stressed with this, I'm used to just using the 'blaaah'.count('a') method. Question, the "symbol" variable you used is that the same as my "Ch" so I can keep that, and I did not know about the 4 spaces! My professor has us use the tab, thanks

Comment: Yes, you can name variable whatever you want until you and everybody who reads your code understand its meaning. About the professor - that's surprising. You know, you can customize many editors to make them put several (including 4) spaces when pressed tab (instead of putting actual tab symbol), maybe that's what he means, and you lost this information somehow? @MrWhal3

Comment: So, if I put exactly what's here, keep my three for loops and use what you did for reading the file, and also changed the variable names(close the file as well) I should be good?

Comment: I did exatly what you had and put my ch in there, I'll put it in here, used python four space method and such> Even doing so, I still got a blank result.

Comment: """ def main():

    try:
    
        string_input = open('text.txt', 'r')
    
        string = string_input.read()
    
        uppercase = uppercase_counter(string)
        lowercase = lowercase_counter(string)
        digit = digit_counter(string)
    
        for ch in string:
            if ch.isupper():
                count1 = count1 + 1
                print(count1)

        return count1       
                
        string_input.close()            
                
    except:
    
        print('Error')
main()

Comment: @andrewchervatkin

Comment: What error, what's its traceback and message? And why did you put your code in 3 double-quotes? You definetly should remove them to make it work @MrWhal3

Comment: I fixed my issue, Community question here for everyone, when I ran my program with .isspace,  I got 871 for the whitspace count from my text file. I also got 144 for just, " ", and that's just from the space bar.. Which would be the total white space? I'll put my code here

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simple.

You have to *open* and *read* this file content... this .txt file. So try this:

```
someFile = open('file.txt')      # Open the file
fileContent = someFile.read()    #Read its content and store it in fileContent variable
```

Now, you have to iterate over the string contained in `fileContent`.

```
count = {}
for character in fileContent:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] = count[character] + 1

print(count)
```

The program loops over each character in the `fileContent` variable’s string, counting how often each character appears.

Finally, the output will be a dictionary where the keys are each kind of character and values are the number of time they appears, that includes all lowercase letters, uppercase letters and space characters.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Set default character would be like, ".islower" correct? Something like; count.islower(character)?? I may be thinking too much on ALL of this and leaving little/major key parts I should know, but yes you helped, thanks

Comment: With your example, where would I put the character exactly, since I am looking for the number of lower/uppercase letter, digits and Han white spaces?

Comment: Let say you have in your .txt file the following string: 'Hello world!'

Comment: The output should be something like this: {' ': 1, '!': 1, 'H': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'w': 1} This means you have ONE whitespace, ONE especial character (!), ONE uppercase letter (H) one lowercase letter (d)... and so on.

Comment: This code will show you all characters types in your file, it automatically includes lowercase and uppercase characters since both type of characters are differents.

Comment: If I put exactly what you had, but changed the names and used my .txt file. That  would be exactly what I need? Is the character variable in the for loop something I need to change?

Comment: I got my code to work the way you had it, now how would I read, or just count, the character types, for example I want JUST uppercase letters to be counters and than to beable to put: print('the number of uppercase characters:, count_uppercaseletters)

Comment: I need to do it for upper/lowercase, digits, and whitespaces.

Comment: Hope youcan continue to help! @Francisco